# Any possibility to access firebase admin through functions internally?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I need to access firebase admin through **Firebase functions**. I have a function that is being called through an HTTP trigger, and will create custom auth tokens.

In the [Firebase admin documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), they say that you need to refer to the `JSON` file containing all the keys (`serviceAccount`)

```
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<databaseName>.firebaseio.com"
})
```

Since i'm already inside my own Firebase functions, will i need to upload these keys or can I access this in any other way?

It feels very unnecessary uploading all my admin keys to Firebase storage just to mint new tokens...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`functions.config().firebase`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.config.Config#firebase) to obtain the Firebase config instance and then pass this directly to the `initializeApp()` method of the Admin SDK:

> ```
> var admin = require("firebase-admin");
> var functions = require("firebase-functions");
>
> // Pass the Firebase config directly to initializeApp() to auto-configure
> // the Admin Node.js SDK.
> admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
> ```

From the [use environment configuration to initialize a module documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#use_environment_configuration_to_initialize_a_module):

> When you deploy functions using the Firebase CLI, `functions.config().firebase` is auto-populated with configuration needed to initialize the [firebase-admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin).
>
> So you can put this in your code:
>
> ```
> const functions = require('firebase-functions');   
> const admin = require('firebase-admin');
> admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
> ```

It has been noted that `functions.config()` is only available within the Cloud Functions hosted environment and therefore [not available when emulating functions locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42978220/2754146). As a workaround, you can export `functions.config()` to `.runtimeconfig.json` by running the following command inside your functions directory:

> ```
> firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json
> ```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: great, but it wont work when serving functions locally using functions-emulator.

Comment: @Qasim See [this answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42978220/2754146) which points to [serve HTTP functions from the command line documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#serve_http_functions_from_the_command_line). Specifically try running: `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json` in your functions directory.

Comment: @Grimthorr yup, that's what i'm using for local env, thanks

Comment: This is not working for me, i got the next error:

Error updating user:  { Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token