# How do I switch to another serviceAccountKey.json via .firebaserc on Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

In my `.firebaserc` file, I provided two Firebase databases, one for dev and one for production:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "db-dev",
    "production": "db-prod"
  }
}
```

So when I'm deploying to production, I'll just run:

```
firebase use production
firebase deploy --only functions
```

My problem is I'm also using cloud storage in one of my cloud functions, so I have two different `serviceAccountKey.json` files that I will use here:

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({ keyFilename: 'serviceAccountKey.json' })
```

My question is how do I automatically switch to another `serviceAccountKey.json` when I switch to another database via `firebase use`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Firebase project will have its own [Environment Configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env). The solution is to store the service account keys there.

**Set the service account key for each Firebase project:**

```
firebase use default
firebase functions:config:set admin.key="serviceAccountKey-dev.json"

firebase use production
firebase functions:config:set admin.key="serviceAccountKey-prod.json"
```

**The environment configuration will be available via `functions.config()`:**

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({ 
  keyFilename: functions.config().admin.key 
})
```

Comment: NOTE: After running `functions:config:set`, you must redeploy functions to make the new configuration available in Firebase.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42978220/365261) also shows how to use `functions.confg()` when testing your Cloud Functions locally.

Answer (score 1):

`firebase use` doesn't have any way to do anything automatically like this.  It simply attaches a Firebase project to your local project folder.  It just manages `.firebaserc` for you.

You're going to have to find another way to get this done.  Maybe write a script that manages both the credentials and `firebase use`?

Comment: Understood. I'll just add a script to my `package.json`.