# When can firebase.config be different to functions:functions:get?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I've set the env variables as defined in docs:
`firebase functions:config:set someservice.key="THE API KEY" someservice.id="THE CLIENT ID"`

When `functions.config()` is called, the variables are not found(there is an outdated test-key), but the new config is not present. However, when I call `firebase functions:config:get` - I get the necessary object, with updated API keys.

What can I do to use env variables properly?
The latest version of functions is deployed, but `functions.config()` is not updated, both locally and live.

Comment: Hi @Animus, have redeploy functions after running the command?

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB Yes, I've run the function after redeploying, but the config is still wrong. At this point, I've found that `config:set` is settings env variables for a particular namespace, so it seems like I might be using a different namespace to the one I'm setting variables for.

Comment: Could you please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841453/running-cloud-functions-locally-gives-error-functions-config-is-not-available) and see if it helps. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I'm checking it for sure since this behavior is extremely strange...

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB Thank you, thank you, thank you! 
I was thinking that it takes the config from the deployed functions all the time!!!!